# How can I combine two collection in mongoDB and also fulfill the following conditions?

Tags: mongodb

**Note**: Each collection contains 96.5k documents and each collection have these fields --

```
{
  "name": "variable1",
  "startTime": "variable2",
  "endTime": "variable3",
  "classes": "variable4",
  "section": "variable"
}
```

**I have 2 collections. I have to compare these 2 collection and have to find out whether some specific fields( here I want name, startTime, endTime) of the documents are same in both the collection.**

**My approach was to join these 2 collection and then use $lookup .. I also tried the following query but it didn't work.
Please help me.**

```
col1.aggregate([
    {
        "$unionWith": {"col1": "col2"}
    },
    {
        "$group":
            {
                "_id":
                    {
                        "Name": "$Name",
                        "startTime": "$startTime",
                        "endTime": "$endTime"
                    },
                "count": {"$sum": 1},
                "doc": {"$first": "$$ROOT"}
            }
    },
    {
        "$match": {"$expr": {"$gt": ["$count", 1]}}
    },
    {
        "$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": "$doc"}
    },
    {
        "$out": "newCollectionWithDuplicates"
    }
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're approach is fine you just have a minor syntax error in your [$unionWith](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/), it's suppose to be like so:

```
{
  "$unionWith": {
    coll: "col2",
    pipeline: []
  }
}
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IsgFetog7_V)

Comment: Thank you soo much Tom. Just want to ask you one more question ...actually the datatype of "startTime" is TimeStamp that means in this format... startTime"2021-12-05T12:00:00Z".....I want to only count this filed as same when the time part is same irrespective of the date part(date part can differ). How can I achieve this?

Comment: You mean you want it grouped by `12:00:00` and ignore the `2021-12-05`? is it saved as `string` or `Date`?

Comment: right..it is saved as string

Comment: You can do something like this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Tkeh3WbHmPc